# Why Nessus freezes at 0% and how to fix it?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

Does anybody know why Nessus freezes at 0%?
I am not sure that I've done the right configuration, but it is becoming painful
How long approximately takes to scan one machine?

[image: configuration]

[image: Configuration]

[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things to look at.

- Try a basic scan of one machine on the same subnet as you, if that hangs for a long time it could be a problem with the system that's doing the scanning or the install of Nessus
- Are you running from the VMWare appliance?  If you are check the networking on that.  If you run nessus over a network card in NAT mode it will go very slowly and may not complete at all.  Bridged mode is the best one to use for that.
- as @D3C4FF says how long is it hanging for?  depending on the number of hosts and network connectivity to them it can take a while to get going.
- Lastly if you've not already, try posting on the Tenable security forums, they're usually pretty responsive over there and if it's a specific nessus problem they may well be best placed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The initial scans (still showing 0%) can take a variable amount of time before any information is presented to you. How long have you waited? 
It's also dependant on your link speed, the speed of your machine and the speed of the machine that you are testing.

Perhaps try a simple scan first with the minimal amount of options set. Additionally, try scanning with a different tool such as nmap and see if you can get any results from that.

Good luck!